# Equality involving fractional part

Tags: calculus

$\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac{\left\{t\right\}}{t^2}\;{dt} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{t-k}{t^2}\,{dt}$

Could someone please explain this equality please?

Comment: Just use the definition of $\{t \} = t - k$ for $k \leq t < k+1$

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $t \in [k, k + 1)$ then $\{t\} = t - k$. Then

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} \, dt = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \int_k^{k + 1} \frac{\{t\}}{t^2} \, dt$$

Comment: correct the typos